# Type of usage in this example

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> The reasons supporting the rise of veganism are developments on those
> explored through vegetarianism – *the idea that animals are not simply
> commodities for human consumption and exploitation.*
>
> The compound was huge with poison gas vents - *a big room designed to
> be used ony once.*

Are these both noun phrases in apposition?

The phrase in the first example doesn't relate with any word. It is describing a philosphical argument that isn't mentioned in the opening sentence. So surely it's not in apposition?

Should it not read: "and those include the idea that animals are not simply (ect)"

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is verbose and unclear, but it is not ungrammatical. I do not want to get into a definitional dispute over appositional phrases, but, at least using a broad definition, "the idea that" is in apposition to "the reasons supporting." This becomes clear if we recast the sentence to say clearly what was intended

> The ideas supporting veganism, for example the idea that animals are not mere commodities to be exploited, are developments of the thoughts behind vegetarianism.

The second sentence **may** follow the same structure, but is even more poorly written.

In both sentences, notice that the words apparently intended to be paired, namely "reasons" and "idea" as well as "room" and "compound," obscure that intention. In the first case, one of the pair is plural and the other singular, but at least an idea can be a reason for something. In the second case, the words do not even relate to the same thing: a room is not a compound.

Grammatical English can express nonsense or be vague.